# App with push notification submit to app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I want to submit my app which uses push notifications. Now i have a app id in provisioning portal which has push notifications enabled for PRODUCTION but not for DEVELOPMENT. Do i have to enable push notifications for DEVELOPMENT as well for submitting to app store?. Also the provisioning profile for app store is to be created in the usual way or is there something different involved?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you don't have to enable Push for Development to submit in the store, only enable for Production it will do. But make sure you have used the same app id to create your Distribution Profile, and submitted to store.

Answer (score 0):

@iphonic is correct you only use the development certificate for development and you use production for Ad-Hoc or App Store submissions.